How to get locale in non-page server-side components on Nextjs 14 app router?
I am developing a new Nextjs 14 app router project, using next-i18n-router & react-i18next to handle localization. I followed nextjs documentation and the provided tutorials in localization setup:

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/internationalization
https://i18nexus.com/tutorials/nextjs/react-i18next

I can access locale for client-side components via useTranslation Hook, however in server-side components I get locale in params object only in page components, then I have to make prop-drilling until I reach the target component to access current locale in nested server-side components.
Is there any way to avoid prop-drilling in server-side components to access current locale?
here is an example of page server-side component:
import styles from './page.module.css';
import ExampleClientComponent from '@/components/ExampleClientComponent';
import initTranslations from '../i18n';

export default async function Home({ params: { locale } }) {
  const { t } = await initTranslations(locale, ['home']);

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h1>{t('header')}</h1>
      <ExampleClientComponent />
      <ExampleServerComponent locale={locale}/>
    </main>
  );
}

That's what I want:
import styles from './page.module.css';
import ExampleClientComponent from '@/components/ExampleClientComponent';
import initTranslations from '../i18n';

export default async function Home({ params: { locale } }) {
  const { t } = await initTranslations(locale, ['home']);

  return (
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h1>{t('header')}</h1>
      <ExampleClientComponent />
      <ExampleServerComponent /> // To have a way to get access to locale without passing it as prop
    </main>
  );
}


I have solved prop-drilling by extracting locale from request headers
Here is the example server-side component without passing local as prop:
import initTranslations from '../i18n';
import { headers } from "next/headers";

export default async function ExampleServerComponent() {
  const reqHeaders = headers();
  const cookie = reqHeaders.get("Cookie");
  
  local = cookie?.split("NEXT_LOCALE=").at(1)?.substring(0, 2); // "en" | "ar";
  const { t } = await initTranslations(locale, ['home']);

  return (
      <h1>{t('title')}</h1>
  );
}

